# Java Slick: Keyboard Input

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm doing my own input window with slick, user will need to type something into this. But when I type any letter I get more than one. I assume it depends on CPU, my current bypass is to sleep thread for 100 ms whenever I type. Is there any other way to do this and get only one letter ?

This is my code

```
    if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_0)) {
        IPInput += "0";
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you can use isKeyPressed instead?

Comment: I just checked and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of my comment....

You can substitute `isKeyPressed()` in for `isKeyDown()`.

KeyPress - triggered when the user presses a key and releases it (key down and then key up)

KeyDown - triggered when the user presses the key (key down)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use keyboard listeners, who has better control over what you are using your keyboard for.

In one of your BasicGameStates you can use:

```
public class Game extends BasicGameState{

public String answer = "";


    public void keyPressed(int key, char c) {

            if (key == Input.KEY_0) {
                answer += "0";
            }

                super.keyPressed(key, c);
    }

    public void keyReleased(int key, char c) {

            if (key == Input.KEY_0) {
                answer += "0";
            }

                super.keyReleased(key, c);
    }
}
```

The keyPressed response is when the key gets PRESSED rather than the other which reacts when the key is RELEASED.